# Regex: matches to new line or end of line or space in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to extract `:privacy` and `:date` from the example string below.

I wanted to have a regex constraint that describes that a `:[^:\s]+` block (e.g. `:privacy` or `:date`) can only be ended
by a space `\s` or a newline `\n` or a end of string `$` (so I will be able to have a rule to logically split these blocks in the later steps).

So I simply put `(?:$|\n|\s)` at the end of the regex, but I doesn't work for me (the 3rd regex below). I double checked that it does work when
I separately put `\s` or `$` (the 1st and 2nd regex below), now I have no idea how I can implement the thing. Thanks for your help.

```
'note::tmp hogehoge. :privacy :date'.match(/\s:[^:\s]+\s/g)
(1) [' :privacy ']

'note::tmp hogehoge. :privacy :date'.match(/\s:[^:\s]+$/g)
(1) [' :date']

'note::tmp hogehoge. :privacy :date'.match(/\s:[^:\s]+(?:$|\n|\s)/g)
(1) [' :privacy ']
```

Comment: look forward `(?=$|\n|\s)`

Comment: @ProGu Tried it and solved! Thanks a lot. Could you put your answer below?

Comment: @ProGu, that's the same as `(?=$|\s)` (since newlines are whitespace). That can also be written `(?!\S)`.

Comment: You are absolute right. I just comment a problem in the code and minimum change to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below regex pattern to match a block pattern :[^:\s+]+ ended by a space \s or a newline \n or a end of string $

```
/((:[^:\s+]+)(?:[\s\n]))|(:[^:\s+]+)(?:[\s\n])?$/gm

(?:[\s\n]) - will check if the block is being followed by a space or a new line
(:[^:\s+]+)(?:[\s\n])?$ - will check if the block is at the end of string or not.
```

you can also use lookforward technique to achieve the same result

```
(:[^:\s+]+)(?=\s|\n|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your pattern `\s:[^:\s]+\s` you are matching the leading and the trailing whitespace chars.

What you might do is assert a whitespace boundary using `(?!\S)` to the right.

To get the value without the leading whitespace char, you can use a capture group.

```
\s(:[^:\s]+)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tAMxub/1)

```js
const s = "note::tmp hogehoge. :privacy :date";
const regex = /\s(:[^:\s]+)(?!\S)/g;
const result = Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1]);
console.log(result);
```